# Change the datetme2 format on the model object level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a datetime2(7) on my asp.net mvc. But currently the date is saved in the database as:-

```
2013-07-12 14:27:47.7934737
```

While on the razor view it will be displayed using `@String.Format("{0:g}", item.DateTimeStart)` as

```
7/12/2013 2:27 PM.
```

So my question if there is a way to modify the current data field format on the model level (not on each view), so that it is displayed as :-

```
12 July 2013 02:27:47 PM.
```

Comment: The data will be saved to the database as a `DateTime2` value - it doesn't *have* a format... likewise I'd expect the value in the model to be `DateTime`. String representation is a *view* concern, not a *model* concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`data annotations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) to set a global display format. Something like this would do the trick

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, 
 DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}")]
public DateTime DateTimeStart { get; set; }
```

Haven't tested the format so you should verify that `dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` is what you're looking for.

Comment: actually this will work , but it displayed the date as  7/12/2013 3:06:11 PM. while I was trying to display the month as July not 7.

Comment: I wan to display the date in the following format "12 July 2013 3:06:11 PM". I am suing "@Html.DisplayTextFor(model=>item.DateTimeStart)" to display the values.

Comment: @JohnPeter: I believe you have to use `DisplayFor` instead of `DisplayTextFor` as this last one doesn't take into account data annotations

Comment: you are right , I changed it to Displayfor and it worked fine. thanks